# Laravel - How to capture Ajax Request Payload Data?

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, ajax-request

**Not a Duplicate Question!!!**

---

Here is my code, using **Laravel 5.4**.

---

### Form in .blade.php file:

```
<form id="read-data-form" name="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="comCode" id="comCode" type="hidden" value=""/>
                <label><span class="text-danger">*</span> Upload File :</label>
                <input name="file" id="fileToUpload" type="file" accept="text/*" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 ">
            <div class="text-right">
                <button type="submit" class="btn operations-btn btn-default" id="upload">Upload</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn operations-btn btn-default" id="stop">Stop</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

### Ajax-request in .js file:

```
$("form #read-data-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  

    var formData = new FormData(this);

    var promise = $.ajax({
        url: 'read_data/file/check',
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        encode: true
    });
    promise.done(function(response){
    });
    promise.fail(function(error){
    });
    promise.always(function(){
    });
}
```

---

### Browser Console > Network > Headers > Request Payload:

### [image]

### Route in web.php file:

```
Route::post('read_data/file/check', 'ReadDataController@checkFile');
```

---

### checkFile() method in ReadDataController.php file:

```
public function checkFile(Request $request)
{
    $comCode = trim($request->comCode);

    $file = $request->file('file');
    dd($file);
}
```

---

### Browser Console > Network > Preview > Request Payload:

This is how output of dd(). 
[image]

---

### Issue:

File could not be captured as in a normal 'multipart/form-data' form without ajax request.

Comment: You are getting all the detail, what is your actual problem ? what do you mean by `normal 'multipart/form-data'` ?

Comment: normal means without using ajax

Comment: problem is that getting the details without file 'name' attribute. I want to capture the file by 'name'.

Comment: when you click on `Upload` button you are not getting file, Right ?

Comment: No, I am getting the file. But, I couldn't capture it by 'name'.

Comment: here `name="file"` name is `file` what name you want ?

Comment: ya, That's it. I want 'file', which is the value of 'name' attribute.

Comment: what is reason and logic behind this ? why not directly by `file` or just change the name `name='comCode'` ?

Comment: Nope, It's an another scenario. I just want to let know to capture the 'file'.

Comment: you need to bind by its name as the value of comCode as `file`(name of file)

Comment: No. No. Forget 'comCode'. Only concern about 'file'.

Comment: you are getting your file here `$request->file('file');` with name `file'` then what's the problem ? Your question is so confusing. Good luck

Comment: @PasinduJayanath when you submit a form, the data is received by the name of the each input, e.g `name='address'`. In the backend, you get that value using `request()->get('address')` the same thing for your 'file input', you gave it a `name='file'` so, retrieved with `request()->file('file')` the difference of normal text and file is you use `file()` method to retrieve input that is of file type. This mean if you have, `name='picture'` it would be `request()->file('picture')` is this what you mean?

Comment: @Oluwatobi Samuel Omisakin, as I know, if name='address', we can simply get that by $request->address. And in my case, I couldn't get by $request()->file('file'). That's what I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Finally, I have a solution which is given by a senior person.

---

Removed this code:

```
$file = $request->file('file');
```

---

Added the following codes:

```
$uploadDirPath = 'C:/uploaded_files/';
$uploadFile = "moved_uploded_file.txt";

$request->file('file')->move($uploadDirPath, $uploadFile);
$uploaded_file = $uploadDirPath.$uploadFile;
```